# Problems format time in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a big problem with formats.
When VBA write a number (`Time() - actualtime`) the result is in seconds, but excel thinks that is days! 
so, when i put this command: 
`Selection.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss.00"`  the seconds are days!

A solution is adding `/(24*3600)` but this is give me an error, perhaps because it is a really small number.

`ActiveCell = ((Timer() - startTime)` where starttime is a `Timer()` define some time back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the type conversion. Because 3600 and 24 are both integers, the result of multiplying them are converted to a 16 bit Int. A 16 bit Int has a range of -32768 to +32767

You can see this by running the following line which does not give an error and returns back 32767

```
MsgBox 32766 + 1
```

Whereas the below line fails with an overflow error due to it exceeding the maximum value.

```
MsgBox 32766 + 2
```

---

As it has already been mentioned, you can circumvent this by dividing the values separately

`(Time() - actualtime) / 3600 / 24` will work..

Also, you can tell excel that you want to use a different type,

```
 MsgBox (Time() - actualtime) / (24# * 3600)   'use Double
 MsgBox (Time() - actualtime) / (24& * 3600)   'use Long
```

The hash or ampersand after the 24 tells excel that you want the value to be used as a defined type and these statements won't fail with an overflow error.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Timeserial(0,0,Time() - actualtime)
```

Timeserial will return a time value, and putting the value you want in the "seconds" argument will ensure the number returned is treated correctly.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Fascinating.

```
actualtime / (24 * 3600)
```

produces an overflow error in VBA.

```
actualtime / 24 / 3600
```

does not.

Something about multiplying 24 and 3600 produces an overflow error.